# Thread safety and AfxMessageBox

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, mfc

Is the AfxMessageBox function thread safe?

I see the MFC code behind AfxMessageBox invoking such as AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd() and CCmdTarget::GetRoundingFrame_()->GetSafeHwnd(), and I'm wondering about its thread safety.

If I have multiple GUI threads, is it OK to invoke AfxMessageBox from either of them?

Comment: Do those GUI threads have their own message loops? Or you have a single GUI thread (usually main thread) and worker threads? You might have problems if calling `AfxMessageBox` from worker threads.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with thread-safety, the failure mode is a message box popping behind another window.  Completely invisible to the user, not modal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is thread-safe. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waas15s1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If AfxGetMainWnd is called from the application's primary thread, it returns the application's main window according to the above rules. If the function is called from a secondary thread in the application, the function returns the main window associated with the thread that made the call.